# Why can't I appendChild my list item

Tags: javascript, html, appendchild

I am trying to get my Events' name shown accordingly in the Calendar. The names are all retrieved from local storage. However, I can't seem to append the name to the months div. While debugging, it said "cannot read property of 'appendChild' of null".

Here are my codes:

```
<table border="1" id="list" style="width:40%">
 <caption style="text-align:center; margin:5px; font-weight:bold; font-size:30px; margin-bottom:10px">
     LIST OF EVENTS 
</caption>


<tr><th>Month</th><th>Events Name</th></tr>
<tr>
<td>January</td>
<td>
<ul id="jan">
</ul>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>February</td>
<td>
<ul id="feb">
</ul>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>March</td>
<td>
<ul id="mar">
</ul>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>April</td>
<td>
<ul id="apr">
</ul>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>May</td>
<td>
<ul id="may">
</ul>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>June</td>
<td>
<ul id="jun">
</ul>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>July</td>
<td>
<ul id="july">
</ul>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>August</td>
<td>
<ul id="aug">
</ul>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>September</td>
<td>
<ul id="sept">
</ul>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>October</td>
<td>
<ul id="oct">
</ul>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>November</td>
<td>
<ul id="nov">
</ul>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>December</td>
<td>
<ul id="dec">
</td>
</tr>

</table>
```

The javascript:

```
var retrieve=localStorage.getItem("CreateEvent");
        var events=JSON.parse(retrieve);

    function addToCalendar(events) {
        var monthIds = ["jan", "feb", "mar", "apr", "may", "jun", "july", "aug", "sept", "oct", "nov", "dec"];
        var index;

        for (index = 0; index < events.length; ++index) {
            var entry = events[index];          
            var dateOfEvent = new Date(entry.date);
            var monthOfEvent = dateOfEvent.getMonth();

          var listitem=document.createElement("LI");
          var entryMarkup = document.createTextNode(entry.name);
          listitem.appendChild(entryMarkup);
          var monthElement = document.getElementById(monthIds[monthOfEvent]);
          monthElement.appendChild(listitem);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Code seems fine - only thing that I could think of is something to be wrong with `entry.date`, thus having **Invalid Date** and from there everything goes bad. Can you give some sample data for `events`?

Comment: @metal03326 events=[{"name":"FUNdraising","pos":["One"],"venue":"Auditorium","date":"2016-08-18","timeStart":"16:00","timeEnd":"20:00","contact":"12345678","email":"a@a.com","desc":"Description here","author":"MyName"},{"name":"Save Money","pos":["One","Two"],"venue":"Sports Hall","date":"2016-09-04","timeStart":"16:00","timeEnd":"19:00","contact":"11112222","email":"aaaa@a.p","desc":"Description here ","author":"MyName2"}]

Comment: JSON validator threw error on that object, but it might have something to do with the copy-paste from Stackoverflow, because I don't see it here. Anyway - I've put all the parts in a JS Bin and I don't have any issues with the code - https://jsbin.com/gabeqefoti/edit?html,output